TradingView Vertical Line Drawings and Boxes
//@version=5

strategy("Roih_StratV5", overlay=true, default_qty_value = 100, default_qty_type = strategy.fixed, margin_long=100, margin_short=100,pyramiding = 0, max_lines_count = 500, max_boxes_count = 500)
    
    // Derived from General Settings
    //maxBarsBackIndex = last_bar_index >= settings.maxBarsBack ? last_bar_index - settings.maxBarsBack : 0
    
    g100 = "Consolidation Box"
    draw_consolidation_box = input.bool(title = "Draw Consolidation Box", defval = true, group = g100)
    percent=input(defval=2.5,title="Percent Range", group = g100)
    aLen=input(defval=3,title="Sensitivity", group = g100)
    rangeCol=input(defval=color.orange,title="Range Fill Color", group = g100)
    rangeTran=input(defval=80,title="Range Fill Opacity ", group = g100)
    rangeBdrCol=input(defval=color.blue,title="Range Boader Color", group = g100)
    rangeBdrTran=input(defval=50,title="Range Boader Opacity ", group = g100)
    rangeBdrWth=input(defval=3,title="Range Boader Width "), group = g100
    levelsTran=100
    
    
    
    var pLows=array.new_float(aLen,0.0)
    var pLowsX=array.new_float(aLen,0.0)
    var pl=ta.pivotlow(low,3,2)
    pl:=nz(ta.pivotlow(low,3,2),pl[1])
    var topBreak=false
    var bottomBreak=false
    var acc=false
    
    if pl!=pl[1] and acc==false
        array.shift(pLows)
        array.shift(pLowsX)
        array.push(pLows,pl)
        array.push(pLowsX,time)
    
    rootPivot=array.get(pLows,0)
    rootPivotX=math.round(array.get(pLowsX,0))
    xOffset=(time-time[1])*2
    percentUp=(1+((percent/2)/100))
    percentDown=(1-((percent/2)/100))
    
    rootL=line.new(rootPivotX-xOffset,rootPivot,time_close,rootPivot,xloc=xloc.bar_time,color=color.new(rangeCol,levelsTran),extend=extend.none)
    boxT=line.new(rootPivotX-xOffset,rootPivot*percentUp,time_close,rootPivot*percentUp,xloc=xloc.bar_time,color=color.new(rangeCol,levelsTran),extend=extend.none)
    boxB=line.new(rootPivotX-xOffset,rootPivot*percentDown,time_close,rootPivot*percentDown,xloc=xloc.bar_time,color=color.new(rangeCol,levelsTran),extend=extend.none)
    
    zeroArray()=>
        for i = 0 to array.size(pLows)-1
            array.set(pLows,i,0.0)
            array.set(pLowsX,i,0.0)
    
    //var rangeBox = box.new(0, 0, 0, 0, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    var BoxCounter = 0
    var box rangeBox = na
    var line line2 = na
    var line line3 = na
    if(draw_consolidation_box)
        if array.min(pLows) !=0
            if array.min(pLows)>rootPivot*percentDown and array.max(pLows)<rootPivot*percentUp
                
                if (acc == false)
                    acc:=true
                    rangeBox := box.new(0, 0, 0, 0, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
                    log.info("####################################################### START CONSOLIDATION BOX AT BAR {0}", bar_index)
                    BoxCounter := BoxCounter +1
                    log.info("BoxCounter {0}",BoxCounter)
    
                    cb_left = line.get_x1(boxT)
                    cb_right = line.get_x2(boxT)
                    cb_top = line.get_y1(boxT)*percentUp
                    cb_bottom = line.get_y1(boxB)        
                    line2 := line.new(cb_left, cb_top, cb_left, cb_bottom, width = 1, extend = extend.both,color =color.white,style = line.style_dashed, xloc = xloc.bar_time,force_overlay = true)
                    x11 = str.format("{0,date,HH:mm:ss yyyy.MM.dd}",line2.get_x1())
                    x22 = str.format("{0,date,HH:mm:ss yyyy.MM.dd}",line2.get_x2())
                    log.info("line2 y1 {0}  {1}", x11, line2.get_y1())
                    log.info("line2 y2 {0}  {1}", x22, line2.get_y2())
                    log.info("cb_left {0}",cb_left)
                    log.info("cb_right {0}",cb_right)
                    log.info("cb_top {0}",cb_top)
                    log.info("cb_bottom {0}",cb_bottom)
    
                box.set_lefttop(rangeBox, line.get_x1(boxT), line.get_y1(boxT)*percentUp)
                box.set_rightbottom(rangeBox, line.get_x2(boxT), line.get_y1(boxB))
                box.set_bgcolor(rangeBox, color.new(rangeCol,rangeTran))
                box.set_border_color(rangeBox,color.new(rangeBdrCol,rangeBdrTran))
                box.set_border_width(rangeBox,rangeBdrWth)
    
                cb_left = line.get_x1(boxT)
                cb_right = line.get_x2(boxT)
                cb_top = line.get_y1(boxT)*percentUp
                cb_bottom = line.get_y1(boxB)  
                line2.delete()         
                line2:= line.new(cb_left, cb_top, cb_left, cb_bottom, width = 1, extend = extend.both,color =color.white,style = line.style_dashed, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
               // line.new(cb_left, cb_top, cb_left, cb_bottom, width = 1, extend = extend.both,color =color.white,style = line.style_dashed, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    
    
    cb_left = line.get_x1(boxT)
    cb_right = line.get_x2(boxT)
    cb_top = line.get_y1(boxT)*percentUp
    cb_bottom = line.get_y1(boxB)
    
                
    
    
    if acc==true and close>box.get_top(rangeBox) and barstate.isconfirmed and topBreak==false //and breaks     
        // alert("Break out of Consolidation Box Top")
        topBreak:=true
    else
        topBreak:=false
    
    
    if acc==true and close<box.get_bottom(rangeBox) and barstate.isconfirmed and bottomBreak==false// and breaks  
        // alert("Break out of Consolidation Box Bottom")
        bottomBreak:=true
    else
        bottomBreak:=false
    
    if ((acc==true and pl<rootPivot*percentDown ) or (acc==true and pl>rootPivot*percentUp)and barstate.isconfirmed)
        zeroArray()
        if acc[1]==true
            //acc:=false
            log.info("########################################################### END CONSOLIDATION BOX AT BAR {0}", bar_index)
            //log.info("TOP: {0} ", cb_top)
            //log.info("BOTTOM: {0} ",cb_bottom)
            log.info("BarIndex {0}", bar_index)
            firstPoint3 =  chart.point.now(open)
            secondPoint3 = chart.point.now(close)
          
            //line.new(firstPoint3, secondPoint3, width = 1, extend = extend.both,color =color.white,style = line.style_dashed)
            line3 :=line.new(cb_right, cb_top, cb_right, cb_bottom, width = 1, extend = extend.both,color =color.red,style = line.style_dashed, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
            x1 = str.format("{0,date,HH:mm:ss yyyy.MM.dd}",line3.get_x1() )
            log.info("line3 {0}  {1}", x1, line3.get_y1())
    
 acc:=false

I have a strategy drawing boxes and on each side of each box I draw vertical lines (using all the screen).
The starting line (left side of each box) is white, and the ending line (right side of box) is red.
For some reason the code does not draw lines on all the boxes, only draws on just the last 2 or three boxes.
I set max_lines_count = 500, max_boxes_count = 500 but still it does not change the situation.Thank you in advance for any advice.
I tried linking the creation of each box to the creation of the starting vertocalline, but still I do not get lines for each box.

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
Could you please share your code

Hi, code added.

@Gu5tavo71  Added. Thank you for any input.

Gu5tavo71  Added. Thank you for any input

Your code does not plot boxes or lines
